# How to create a popup window in admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, popup

How to create a popup window in admin panel?

I want to open a popup window when a custom button on the sales/order page is clicked to show details to the customer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

### Popup window

Magento has a shortcut JavaScript function for popup windows, defined in `js/varien/js.js`:

```
function popWin(url,win,para)
```

The parameters are the same as in [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

#### Example:

```
popWin(
    "http://www.domainname.ext/path/ImageFile.png",
    "DescriptiveWindowName",
    "resizable,scrollbars,status")
```

### Popup layer

In the admin area you have also access to the prototype.js [`Window`](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/) plugin that can open a layer with control elements and arbitrary content, which can be an external URL. In that case it is loaded into an iframe.

#### Example:

```
var url ='http://www.domainname.ext/path/ImageFile.png'
var win = new Window({
    className:'magento',
    title:'Enter Window Title',
    url:url,
    width:820,
    height:600,
    minimizable:false,
    maximizable:false,
    showEffectOptions: {duration:0.4},
    hideEffectOptions:{duration:0.4}
});
win.setZIndex(100);
win.showCenter(true);
```

It's also possible to load the window content via AJAX instead of in an iframe, see: [Window.setAjaxContent()](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/documentation.html#setAjaxContent)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('document.aspx','mywindowtitle','width=500,height=750')">open window</a>
```

If you desire more complex functions, use the php variable "GET"
Using "POST" can be a bit tricky with Backend HTTP/1.1 Validation.